# Updating Value in table based on foreign key association in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables.
Table A

```
@Entity
public class MerchantsInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;
}
```

Table B

```
@Entity
public class MerchantsSdkConfig implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn( name = "merchantId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MerchantsInfo merchant;


    private String applicationId;
}
```

Now I want to update `applicationId` in Table B through the foreign key `merchantId`. I tried the following

```
@Modifying
@Query("update MerchantsSdkConfig u set u.applicationId = ?1 where u.merchantId = ?2")
public int updateApplicationId(String applicationId, Long merchantId);
```

But I keep getting the error below

> could not resolve property: merchantId of: com.bus.api.entity.MerchantsSdkConfig [update com.bus.api.entity.MerchantsSdkConfig u set u.applicationId = ?1 where u.merchantId = ?2]

Comment: Well, look at your entity: it doesn't have any property named `merchantId`. So `u.merchantId = ?2` can't be correct. You want `u.merchant = ?2`, and you need to pass a MerchantsInfo with the right ID.

Comment: Try 'where u.merchant.id = ?2" '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Modifying
@Query("update MerchantsSdkConfig u set u.applicationId = ?1 where u.merchant.id = ?2")
public int updateApplicationId(String applicationId, Long merchantId);
```

Thanks to the comments on the question. I was able to solve the following with the above.

Apparently I had to reference/access the mapped table, before getting to the column I needed.